# Access ApplicationComponent from outer package

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have the following structure:

```
|-FirstLibrary
| |——MyActivity (extends BaseActivity)
|
|-SharedLibrary
| |——BaseActivity
|
|-CoreLibrary
  |——MyApplication
  |——ApplicationComponent
  |——ApplicationModule
  |——FirstLibraryModule
```

The CoreLibrary is compiling FirstLibrary and SharedLibrary and FirstLibrary is compiling SharedLibrary.

I am creating the modules injections at ApplicationComponent and initialising it at MyApplication.
The problem I am facing is to inject the ApplicationComponent into MyActivity as MyApplication is not accessible from FirstLibrary Package. Is there any way to sort it?

I am using Dagger 2.11.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. So ``FirstLibrary`` doesn't depend on the ``CoreLibrary``?

Comment: Need more clarification.

Comment: @Fred right now the project has DI with Roboguice and 'CoreLibrary' is the package where the injection is done, so 'CoreLibrary' has added 'FirstLibrary' dependency to inject the corresponding 'FirstLibrary' class.